# Assembly - meaning of symbol (C) in instruction syntax

Tags: assembly

I look into Zilog Z80 manual, the syntax for input:

```
IN A,(n)
IN r,(C)
```

What does the `(n)` and `(C)` mean? I guess `r` means any register and `A` register A. Sorry for such a trivial question, could you give me a link where it is well explained?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
IN A,(n)
```

Per [the manual](http://www.zilog.com/appnotes_download.php?FromPage=DirectLink&dn=UM0080&ft=User%20Manual&f=YUhSMGNEb3ZMM2QzZHk1NmFXeHZaeTVqYjIwdlpHOWpjeTk2T0RBdmRXMHdNRGd3TG5Ca1pnPT0=), page 292:

> The operand n is placed on the bottom half (A0 through A7) of the
>   address bus to select the I/O device at one of 256 possible ports.

In other words, the actual value of `n` (ranging from 0 to 255) is placed on address lines A0 through A7. The contents of the accumulator (`A`) are placed on the top address lines A8 through A15. This selects one of I/O device ports whose port address is `XXYY` where `XX` are the contents of `A`, and `YY` is the value of `n`, so those ports range in address form `XX00` to `XXFF`.

```
IN r,(C)
```

Per [the manual](http://www.zilog.com/appnotes_download.php?FromPage=DirectLink&dn=UM0080&ft=User%20Manual&f=YUhSMGNEb3ZMM2QzZHk1NmFXeHZaeTVqYjIwdlpHOWpjeTk2T0RBdmRXMHdNRGd3TG5Ca1pnPT0=), page 293:

> The contents of Register C are placed on the bottom half (A0 through
>   A7) of the address bus to select the I/O device at one of 256 possible
>   ports.

Here, the *contents* of register `C` are placed on address lines A0 through A7, and the contents of register `B` are placed on address lines A8 through A15. Together, they form a port address `XXYY` where `XX` are the contents of `B`, and `YY` are the contents of `C`, and select an I/O device port, one of 256 possible (numbered 0 through 255, per contents of `C`). The port address, as above, range from `XX00` to `XXFF` per contents of `C`. The results of reading the port are stored in register `r`.